# Fixed effect model - using plm and lm, different R2 values

Tags: r, fixed, lm, plm

I tried to do fixed effect model using plm and lm + factor(countries).
And I got the same values for estimators, but I got different values for R2, residual standard error and F-statistic. Why?

And the second question - can I get the coefficients for countries using the plm? (similar to lm + factor(countries))

Here is my data set: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8r0vl85rb1ak6e/panel_data.csv?dl=0
There are some financial measures and GDP growth for some countries and several years. There are some NAN's (panel in unbalanced)

```
proba<-read_excel("my_data.xlsx")

pdata<-pdata.frame(proba,index=c("id","year"))

fixed <-plm(GDP_growth~gfdddi01 + gfdddi02 + gfdddi04 + gfdddi05,data=pdata,model="within")

fixed.dum <-lm(GDP_growth~gfdddi01 + gfdddi02 + gfdddi04 + gfdddi05 + factor(country) - 1, data=pdata_srednie_5_letnie)
```

Thank you!

Comment: 'lm()` gives the standard value for r-squared for the OLS model, while `plm(model = "within")` reports the "within" r-squared for the demeaned model. If you want more info, I'd asked this over on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Both questions have been asked before, please see here for answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058092/plm-vs-lm-different-results